# Monotonicity property of a sequence of equi-continuous functions

Tags: analysis, functions, equicontinuity

Suppose that a sequence of equi-continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is such that for the fixed constant $K > 0$, each $f_n: [0, K] \to [0, K]$ and it is strictly increasing.

Take any $x \in (0,K)$. Is it possible to prove that there exists some $\epsilon = \epsilon(x) > 0$ such that by making $\delta = \delta(\epsilon) > 0$ sufficiently small, we have
\begin{equation}
f_n(x) - \epsilon \geq f_n(x-\delta),
\end{equation}
for all $n$?

Answer (score 0):

No, take $f_n(x)=x/n$ in $[0,K]$ for $n\geq 1$. The sequence is equi-continuous and the functions are strictly increasing. On the other hand, for $\epsilon>0$,
$$f_n(x) - \epsilon \geq f_n(x-\delta)$$
if and only if $n\epsilon \leq \delta$ for any $n\geq 1$. This is  a contradiction because the left-hand side is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So do you have an additional condition on $\{f_n\}$ to make the statement hold?

Comment: @user592237 I am afraid not at the moment.